How to include "_" in a serverpod field naming in spy.yaml file with out getting warnings?
I have a database that have column name with underscore notation (full_name) and I working on serverpod mini so connection to Postgres database. I am calling APIs from a supabase.
When I am writing my spy.yaml class I keep getting this warning:
Field names should be valid Dart variable names (e.g. camelCaseString)

On every field I user "_".
Below is the code in the file

When I run serverpod generate everything works fine but how to bypass this warning?
I can not remove the underscore because the json keys are have underscore
Thanks in advance!
